# Grep a list of strings

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep, string

I have a multiple strings that I want to find them in a list of files that are in a same folder. So, I want to put all the strings in a sort of list and then apply the command: `grep -l string *`,so I can be able to list all the files where the strings could them be.

How can I do it?. I was thinking of doing something like: `grep -l string1 * | grep -l string2 * | grep -l string3 *`. But the list of strings is longer than 3 strings.

Comment: So a file matches if it contains *all* the strings, right? In the same line? or wherever?

Comment: Do you want to find the names of the files that contain matches for _all_ patterns, or just for any pattern?

Comment: `grep -l pat1 |grep pat2` would first look for files that contain the first pattern, and then would look for the second pattern in the file _names_. I'm not exactly sure what you want here: do you want to find files that contain _all_ the given patterns? Or _lines_ that contain all patterns? Or lines/files that contain _any_ one or more of the patterns?

Answer (score 7):

In order to grep for multiple patterns, you either specify them on the command-line with

```
grep -l -e PATTERN1 -e PATTERN2 -... -e PATTERNn *
```

Or, you put them in a file `patterns.txt` and use that as input

```
grep -l -f patterns.txt *
```

Don't hesitate to utilize the manual pages:

```
man grep
```

Have fun!
Gerhard